# Android make 10dp gradient border for ImageViews

Tags: android, android-layout, android-shape

I'm using `com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView` library and i'm trying to make simple Gradient border for all of this views, my below xml to make that is not work correctly and i have to use simple view as background now,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <gradient
                android:angle="360"
                android:centerColor="#e95a22"
                android:endColor="#ff00b5"
                android:gradientRadius="360"
                android:startColor="#006386"
                android:type="sweep" />
            <size android:height="90dp"
                android:width="90dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="2dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:left="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size android:width="90dp"
                android:height="90dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/mdtp_white"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and my layout is:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
        android:layout_width="61dp"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image_11"
        app:civ_border_color="#ffffff"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
        app:civ_shadow="false"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_border_color"
        app:civ_shadow_radius="5" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**POST UPDATED WITH SCREEN SHOT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add padding to your Image view

```
<com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
    android:layout_width="71dp"
    android:layout_height="71dp"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:src="@drawable/image_11"
    app:civ_border_color="#ffffff"
    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
    app:civ_shadow="false"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_border_color"
    app:civ_shadow_radius="5" />
```